# Error on generating pdf file Dynamic Reports

Tags: java, servlets, dynamic-reports

I have implemented Dynamic Reports on my project to generate pdf reports (version 4.0.0), but I got this grave error:

> GRAVE: El Servlet.service() para el servlet [com.pkg.svt_pdf] en el contexto con ruta [/WEB] lanzó la excepción [La ejecución del Servlet lanzó una excepción] con causa raíz
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.itextpdf.text.Document.setRole(Lcom/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfName;)V
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:580)
>       at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:519)
>       at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.export(JasperReportBuilder.java:630)
>       at net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.builder.JasperReportBuilder.toPdf(JasperReportBuilder.java:532)
>       at com.pkg.reports.ReportsGenerator.exportPDF(ReportsGenerator.java:73)
>       at com.pkg.svt_pdf.doGet(svt_pdf.java:53)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2440)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2429)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

and this my code:

> ```
>   AbstractJasperExporterBuilder exporter = export.pdfExporter(output);
>     exporter.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
>     JasperReportBuilder jrb = JRBuild(connection);
>     jrb.toPdf((JasperPdfExporterBuilder) exporter);
> ```

the error in this line:

```
jrb.toPdf((JasperPdfExporterBuilder) exporter);
```

Comment: Make sure to add itext library to classpath

Comment: yes its added: itext-pdfa and itextpdf

Comment: @Zouhair double check for classpath , that library file must be added in your page.